# Manage Customers empty

Tags: admin, magento-1, customer, grid, third-party-module

After updating a Magento shop from 1.9.2.* to 1.9.3.7 and migrating it to a new server, everything works good so far. However, opening Customers -> Manage Customers in the Admin panel just shows no list. Please see the picture:

[image: Manage Customers shows no list]

There is no `exception.log`. But checking the `system.log` it shows the following `Warning`:

```
2018-04-08T06:13:47+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Customer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/.../htdocs/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-04-08T06:13:47+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Customer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/.../htdocs/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-04-08T06:13:47+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Customer.php' for inclusion (include_path='...')  in /var/www/.../htdocs/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
```

Unfortunately the warning does not contain a path. And `Customer.php` is pretty general. Doing a file search for `Customer.php` on the server returns multiple results in different directories.

What is the cause of the problem here? Thank you.

Comment: Is there any way I can trace and debug what Magento is trying to do there?

Comment: Try and add the following code in `lib/Varien/Autoload.php` on line 93: `echo $classFile . '<br>'; `.
This should help you to see which file is causing the issue.

Comment: Also, enable error reporting in `index.php`

Comment: The page title in your screenshot suggests an extension has overwritten the standard customer grid. Have you tried looking for the extension and disable it?

Comment: may be file permission issue so find . -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;

Comment: Have you checked apache error log?

Comment: It seems that either this is a folder permission problem or you need to compile your code from System -> Tools -> Compilation to solve the error.

Comment: I think there is some custom extension working on the Manage Customers page. Please check and try disabling the extension. It may not be compatible with the new version of your Magento store.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora Yes, this was the problem. It was caused by the `Templates Master Sold Together` extension. Disabling it in `/app/etc/modules/TM_SoldTogether.xml` and clearing the cache, the `Customer Manager` works again! If you post this as an answer I'll glady accept it as solution. :)

Comment: @MarioWerner, I have posted my suggestions as answer. Please upvote if it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please debug the problem with the following steps:

- First check the error logs of server. There should be some clue.
- It seems that either this is a folder permission problem or you need to compile your code from **`System -> Tools -> Compilation`** to solve the error.
- There may be some custom extension working on the Manage Customers page. Please check and try disabling the extension. It may not be compatible with the new version of your Magento store.

Please check and let me know if the above steps helped.

Comment: Problem was caused by `the Templates Master Sold Together` extension. Disabling it in `/app/etc/modules/TM_SoldTogether.xml` and clearing the cache, the `Customer Manager` works again.

Comment: Please award bounty also if possible :)

Comment: True, sorry. Thought it is automatically when I accept your answer. Done. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling error reporting in index.php file

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

to

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Set `$_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'] = true`

and uncomment this line

```
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

I guess the issue might be custom extension grid which might not have the updated code for the recent Magento Patch.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In file `{magento-root}/lib/Varien/Autoload.php`, Magento is trying to include `Customer.php`

There can be multiple reasons due to which this error can come. But I think it is related to the compilation. Please check the compilation and try checking it by switching it off and then recompiling the code.

Upgrades should be done while keeping the compilation off.

If compilation is not the issue try disabling custom extensions and then check Magento (general debugging technique) as it will let you know the buggy extension which is not compatible with newer version of Magento or the patch.

**Note**: Take the backup of files and database.